# Subsetting columns in different positions and with different names in a large list of lists with purrr

Tags: r

I have a large list of lists. There are 46 lists in "output". Each list is a tibble with differing number of rows and columns. My immediate goal is to subset a specific column from each list.

This is str(output) of the first two lists to give you an idea of the data.

```
> str(output)
List of 46
 $ Brain                          :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    6108 obs. of  8 variables:
 ..$ p_val    : chr [1:6108] "0" "1.60383253411205E-274" "0" "0" ...
 ..$ avg_diff : num [1:6108] 1.71 1.7 1.68 1.6 1.58 ...
 ..$ pct.1    : num [1:6108] 0.998 0.808 0.879 0.885 0.923 0.905 0.951 0.957 0.619 0.985 ...
 ..$ pct.2    : num [1:6108] 0.677 0.227 0.273 0.323 0.36 0.384 0.401 0.444 0.152 0.539 ...
 ..$ cluster  : num [1:6108] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ gene     : chr [1:6108] "Plp1" "Mal" "Ermn" "Stmn4" ...
 ..$ X__1     : logi [1:6108] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ Cell Type: chr [1:6108] "Myelinating oligodendrocyte" NA NA NA ...
$ Bladder                        :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 4656 obs. of  8 variables:
 ..$ p_val    : num [1:4656] 0.00 1.17e-233 2.85e-276 0.00 0.00 ...
 ..$ avg_diff : num [1:4656] 2.41 2.23 2.04 2.01 1.98 ...
 ..$ pct.1    : num [1:4656] 0.833 0.612 0.855 0.987 1 0.951 0.711 0.544 0.683 0.516 ...
 ..$ pct.2    : num [1:4656] 0.074 0.048 0.191 0.373 0.906 0.217 0.105 0.044 0.177 0.106 ...
 ..$ cluster  : num [1:4656] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 ..$ gene     : chr [1:4656] "Dpt" "Gas1" "Cxcl12" "Lum" ...
 ..$ X__1     : logi [1:4656] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 ..$ Cell Type: chr [1:4656] "Stromal cell_Dpt high" NA NA NA ...
```

Since I have a large number of lists that make up the list, I have been trying to create an iterative code to perform tasks. This hasn't been successful.

1. I can achieve this manually, or list by list, but I haven't been successful in finding an iterative way of doing this.

   ```
   x <- data.frame(output$Brain, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   tmp.list <- x$Cell.Type
   tmp.output <- purrr::discard(tmp.list, is.na)
   x <- subset(x, Cell.Type %in% tmp.output)
   ```

This gives me the output that I want, which are the rows in the column "Cell.Type" with non-NA values.

2. I got as far as the code below to get the 8th column of each list, which is the "Cell.Type" column.

   ```
   lapply(output, "[", , 8))
   ```

But here I found that the naming and positioning of the "Cell.Type" column in each list is not consistent. This means I cannot use the lapply function to subset the 8th columns, as some lists have this on for example the 9th column.

3. I tried the code below, but it does not work and gets an error.

   ```
   lapply(output, "[", , c('Cell.Type', 'celltyppe'))
   #Error: Column `celltyppe` not found
   #Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
   ```

Essentially, from my "output" list, I want to subset either columns "Cell.Type" or "celltyppe" from each of the 46 lists to create a new list with 46 lists of just a single column of values. Then I want to drop all rows with NA.

I would like to perform this using some sort of loop.

At the moment I have not had much success. Lapply seems to be able to extract columns through lists iterately, and I am having difficultly trying to subset names columns.

Once I can do this, I then want to create a loop that can subset only rows without NA.

---

FINAL CODE

This is the final code I have used to create exactly what I had hoped for. The first line of the code specifies the loop to go through each list of the large list. The second line of code selects columns of each list that contains "ell" in its name (C**ell** type, C**ell** Type, or c**ell**typpe). The last removes any rows with "na".

```
    purrr::map(output, ~ .x %>% 
        dplyr::select(matches("ell")) %>% 
             na.omit)
```

Comment: I want to subset either. The issue here is inconsistency. Column containing information about cell type is named different for each list ("Cell Type", "Cell type", "celltyppe" etc.)

Comment: I got it.  Please check the soluton posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use anonymous function call

```
lapply(output, function(x) na.omit(x[grep("(?i)Cell\\.?(?i)Typp?e", names(x))]))
#[[1]]
#  Cell.Type
#1         1
#2         2
#3         3
#4         4
#5         5

#[[2]]
#  celltyppe
#1         7
#2         8
#3         9
#4        10
#5        11
```

---

Also with `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(output, ~ .x %>%
               select(matches("(?i)Cell\\.?(?i)Typp?e") %>%
               na.omit))
```

#### data

```
output <- list(data.frame(Cell.Type = 1:5, col1 = 6:10, col2 = 11:15), 
          data.frame(coln = 1:5, celltyppe = 7:11))
```

Comment: This is the error I get. Error: Column `celltyppe` not found
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: @naeum  Do you have the `celltyppe` column in the data.frame

Comment: @naeum  If your description is either one of the column, use a regex to select the column.  I changed the solution.  Check if that works

Comment: yes. `names(output$`Bone marrow`)
[1] "p_val"     "avg_logFC" "pct.1"     "pct.2"     "p_val_adj" "cluster"   "gene"     
[8] "X__1"      "celltyppe"`

Comment: @naeum  Based on the description, I created an example data and the code works on it

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I have updated the post with the final code. It is exactly what I want.

Comment: Hi @akrun. Thanks a lot for yesterday. Following on from yesterday's code. I am realising that for subsequent analysis it is easier if I am able to get information on all other rows (variables), not just values on the "cell type" column. Do you have ideas on how I can adjust the code so that it retrieves all other columns that does not have "na" on the "cell type" column?

Comment: I am having difficult applying inner_join and merge functions for large lists.

Comment: @naeum  I am not getting your comment correctly.  Are you saying that you want to remove the rows having NA on the 'cell type' column?

Comment: @naeum  Try `lapply(output, function(x) x[complete.cases(x[[grep("(?i)Cell\\.?(?i)Typp?e", names(x))]]), ])`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, sorry for not making it clear. What I now want to do is to filter the large list that I have by what I got from yesterday: Rows that have a no NAs on the 'cell type' column.

Comment: purrr::map(output, ~ .x %>%
                                   dplyr::select(matches("ell")) %>%
                                   complete.cases). This code now returns a logical vector. Could I use this logical vector as an input to select all rows that have a value in the "cell type" column?

Comment: It is really difficult to do anything on a complex list of lists. I can't produce codes to break down each list into individual data frames neither can I subset the large list with a condition (so that I can get information on all variables). I would much appreciate if there are any resources/sites/githubs that deal with working with complex lists.

Comment: @naeum  IN the code I showed, it removes rows that have NA elements on the 'Cell Type' columns.  Regarding your code, it should be `filter`.  i.e. `purrr::map(output, ~ .x %>% filter_at(vars(matches("ell")),  funs(any_vars(!is.na(.)))`.

Comment: @akron apologies for the belated reply. Thank you immensely for your help! Although I couldn't manage to get the code right  with the filter function, I did manage in the end to get what I want. Thanks again for all the help :)